# Check bit length of ssl certificates for both, RSA and elliptic curves

Tags: openssl, rsa

We're using a script based on [acme.sh](https://github.com/acmesh-official/acme.sh) to generate our SSL certificates. acme.sh also supports elliptic curves. I wonder, how to check the keylength for both, RSA and elliptic curve certificates. I need to know the keylength (e.g. 256 for ec or 2048 for RSA) to determine if a certificate needs to be replaced.

```
openssl rsa -in privatekey.pem -text -noout | grep "Private-Key"
```

works for RSA but not for elliptic curves.

```
openssl ec -in privatekey.pem -text -noout | grep "Private-Key"
```

Works for elliptic curves, but I then need to distinguish between rsa and ec. There should be an easier way to get the bit length?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply read the certificate with:

```
openssl x509 -noout -text -in unknown.pem | grep 'Public-Key'
```

Which returns: `Public-Key: (2048 bit)` or `Public-Key: (256 bit)`